SVN to Git | --ignore-paths
I have a large svn repository and im trying to migrate to git. Now im struggling using --ignore-paths with git-svn to filter some paths.
I have this repository: https://svn.host.co.mz/svn/sistemas
Then i have a project named project1 and inside project1 i have two branches.
Inside development i have a directory named archive, dev_demo and sprints.
project1

branches/

development
production



project2

branches/

development
-archive
-sprints
-dev_demo
production



I want to clone and fetch only sprints and dev_demo inside development but it always comes with archive path.
I have tried to implement the below .git/config but it´s not working.
       
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true

[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://svn.host.co.mz/svn/sistemas/project1
    fetch = :refs/remotes/origin/project1
    ignore-paths = ^branches/development/(archive|[^/]*/archive)/

I want a regex that matches with the structure of my paths and exlude archive directory.

Why don't you simply put ^branches/development/archive?

If the svn repo contains "too much stuff" but you know exactly what you need — let me suggest changing the approach from a "subtractive" to an "additive" one. Should be way cleaner & easier to understand.
What I mean is, instead of trying to filter out junk with ignores, just map out what you need explicitly:
[svn-remote "svn"]
    # NOTE: it should point to svn repo root, ↓↓↓ no /project1 here
    url = https://svn.host.co.mz/svn/sistemas
    #                                         ↑↑↑

    branches = project1/{development,production}:refs/remotes/project1/branches/*

    fetch = project2/production:refs/remotes/project2/branches/production

    fetch = project2/dev-demo:refs/remotes/project2/branches/development/dev_demo

    branches = project2/sprints/*:refs/remotes/project2/branches/development/sprints/*

The docs --> https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn <--

It is also possible to fetch a subset of branches or tags by using a comma-separated list of names within braces


Multiple fetch, branches, and tags keys are supported

